# Search form Alignment in Aqua marina theme Drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-theming, drupal-themes

I have a problem with Search form alignment with Aqua Marina theme in drupal7. I want search block to be next to Logo (logo to be in the left corner of header and Search form to the right corner of the header). Please can help me with this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Marinelli Theme for your custom need.